# Somewhat bad grades and repeated courses in first few semesters, will it affect my chance to write a bachelors thesis?

Tags: thesis, computer-science, undergraduate, grades

I'm currently studying Computer Science in my 4th year and due to some personal reasons during my first few semesters, I wasn't really performing too well and had to retake a few classes.

Although my grades have improved significantly over the past semesters, I worry that I will have troubles finding a supervisor for my bachelor's thesis. Many professors wish to receive a copy of a student's transcript of records in order for them to apply for a thesis.

Ultimately, my question is, whether the professors will simply reject my proposals based on my grades from first years or if they give you a chance nonetheless. Does anybody have experience with similar situations?

Comment: Which country is this in?

Answer (score 2):

I think it depends on the country and university you are writing from.
In some countries, your failed courses don't count, only the passed ones with their grade and calification.
So in that case, you wouldn't be affected if you just didn't pass. If you passed with a bad grade, that's another thing, because that indeed count.

Nevertheless, I do not know how professors choose their students for the bachelor thesis, and I suppose that it depends on the university and their internal rules. Some may ordered the students by general GPA, other only by the GPA of the last year, in other universities and countries maybe (just maybe) do the failed courses count (or "not presented", that means, you didn't go to the examinations). Or maybe they just choose by order of solicitudes or according to the interest of the topic you proposed for the thesis. There are lots of ways, really... They might also take into account if you participated in this or that other project, or if you had a particular scholarship before, or lot of things...
So far as I know, even in the same faculty may different professors have different ways and criteria for choosing.

So my advice is to know how it works on your faculty, cause it is not the same all over the world when it comes to what you are asking.

Answer (score -1):

I did not see your country, but my experience of working with people from different origins this tends to be universal (any country). Good grades will get you the interview but your life story could give you your job (thesis student). If you have backing evidence (e.g. documentation, doctors notes, etc), you should be fine if the University values your life story. Everyone has a life story. Some people's life story are more meaningful than others. Defining who has a better life story is up to the committee who decides whether to accept you as a thesis student. Now, you should note that if you have a life story that is not compelling, lacks evidence, and motivation (lacks work ethics), any professor who decides to work with you will have a *short temper*. Any signs of underperformance from you, and the professor will drop you. At the bachelors level, it may be more relaxed than at the masters or doctoral level.